# Redirect to Index page when Facebook PHP SDK Access Token is Expired

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0, facebook-php-sdk, fatal-error

I'm working on a site that uses the Facebook PHP SDK.  It is working great, and after 2 hours, whenever I try to get onto one of the general pages on the site, I get...

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.
```

If I go back to the index page, I get a new access token and everything works properly again...for 2 hours.

What code can I put on my webpages to redirect to the index page when the access token has expired?

Thanks for helping this noob.

Comment: Can you use the [JS SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/)?

Answer (score 1):

You must redirect user to page that has authorized code. 
If your user not deauthorized app , the Oauth dialog isn't appear.

For more information go to
[Access Token & Handling](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/debugging-access-tokens/)

Answer (score 0):

You can put a `try / catch` block in your code.

Put each Facebook API call in such block and if an exception occurs you can redirect the user to the right resource by `header('Location: <url>');`:

```
try {
  # FB API call 
} 
catch(OAuthException e) {
  header('Location: <url>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a file that goes like this and include it in your webpages.

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => "app id",
  'secret' => "app secret",
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();

if ($user) {
  try {
    $me = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);   
  }
}
else {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
}
```